# Spring controller escape plus

Tags: java, spring, rest

So let's say I have controller code like this -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/graph/{graphName}/index/{indexName}/")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getResponse(
        @PathVariable String graphName,
        @PathVariable String indexName,
        @RequestParam(value = "searchTerms") List<String> searchTerms) {

    System.out.println("IN CONTROLLER");
    System.out.println(searchTerms);
```

the url that I'm hitting looks like this

```
graph/graph1/index/index1/?searchTerms=123+456
```

When I look at search terms I see [123 456] - how do I make it so that I get [123+456]?

Comment: You need to encode the `+`. That should be `%2B`. I'm not sure if Spring does that itself.

Comment: do you mean in the url?

Comment: Yes, the url should be `graph/graph1/index/index1/?searchTerms=123%2B456`